# How to initialize data in Preview provider in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to fetch data from localhost, make a list of posts with List View and pass data to CustomDetailView. Here is my code for NetworkManager:
[image]

My ListView:
[image]

And StoryDetails View:
[image]

So what I have to pass to StoryDeatils_Preview?

Here is the StoryDetails code

```
import SwiftUI

struct StoryDetails: View {
    var story: Story
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("story #123456")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Spacer()
                Text("5 days ago")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Button(action:{
                    print("Hello there")
                }){
                    Image(systemName:"info.circle").resizable()
                        .frame(width:22.0, height:22.0)
                        .accentColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
            Text(story.body)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .kerning(1)
                .lineLimit(nil)
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Hello World")
                }){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName:"heart")
                            .accentColor(.black)
                        Text("233")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName:"bubble.left")
                            .accentColor(.black)
                        Text("45")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

struct StoryDetails_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StoryDetails(
            story: Story(
                id: 1,
                author: 1,
                body: "Testing",
                edited_time: "September 2019",
                pub_date: "October 2018",
                comments: [Comment](),
                story_likes: [StoryLike]()
             )
        )
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please show the full code of the `StoryDetails`-View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there first I need to see the `StoryDetails()` but if StoryDetails a Story it should be declared inside as `var story: Story` let me explain more in example code:
Here you can see my network manager class:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    let url: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()

    init() {
        fetchData()
    }

    @Published var user: User? {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
            print("set user")
        }
    }
    func fetchData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
        print("fetch data")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {return}
            print("no error")
            guard let data = data else {return}
            print("data is valid")
            let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.user = user
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

that's my content view where network manager is initialized inside:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DetailsView(user: networkManager.user)
        }
    }
}
```

Details view struct holds user variable:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    var user: User?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("id: \(user?.id ?? 0)")
            Text("UserID: \(user?.userId ?? 0 )")
            Text("title: \(user?.title ?? "Empty")")
        }
    }
}
```

and that's the DetailsView as you can see inside of this struct I declared a user object of type User need to be pass it so if I want to show it in PreviewProvider it would be like the code below

```
struct DetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailsView(user: User(id: 0, userId: 0, title: "hello", completed: false)
    }
}
```

model:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    var userId: Int = 0
    var id: Int = 0
    var title: String = ""
    var completed: Bool = false
}
```

> PS: For sure you can unwrap better than this way to provide
>   any nil exception it's just POC

Comment: are you previewing NewsStoriesView_Preview or StoryDetails_Preview?

Comment: Both. StoryDetails displays dummy data that I provided in StoryDetails_preview, but NewStoriesView doesn't show any fetched data

Comment: Okay no problem let's first make sure that fetchData is calling correctly please debug it or put some prints inside of it just to make sure you're receiving the data correctly because as logic you write it well.. and you should have data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203371/discussion-between-ulukbek-abylbekov-and-fakiho).

Comment: I was redirect to his post because of the same situation i am trying to work out. I do not want to provide any value in the View since it fetches data, only to the preview. Even if User?, you still provided an instance. Is this the only way?